# android passing values to another activity but cannot read

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to pass values to a new activity but cannot read the values from the new activity.

here is my code,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Photo2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);

myIntent.putExtra("image1", image1);
myIntent.putExtra("image2", image2);
myIntent.putExtra("image3", image3);

myIntent.putExtra("konteyner_no", _txt_konteyner_id.getText().toString());
myIntent.putExtra("mahalle", _txt_mahalle.getText().toString());
myIntent.putExtra("sokak", _txt_sokak.getText().toString());

myIntent.putExtra("konteyner_temizmi", _check_konteyner_temizmi.isChecked());
myIntent.putExtra("yaninda_cop_varmi", _check_yaninda_cop_varmi.isChecked());
myIntent.putExtra("aralarinda_cop_varmi", _check_aralarinda_cop_vardi.isChecked());
myIntent.putExtra("zamansiz_cop_varmi", _check_zamansiz_cop_vardi.isChecked());
myIntent.putExtra("cop_obekleri_vardi", _check_cop_obekleri_vardi.isChecked());

myIntent.putExtra("note", _txt_note.getText().toString());

startActivity(myIntent);
```

how do I read them from the new activity(MainActivity)?

Comment: if its primitive types that you want to pass then check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859445/how-do-you-pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another/15859488#15859488. Are you passing images??

Comment: I have 3 bitmaps that I am sending

Comment: for bitmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459524/how-can-i-pass-a-bitmap-object-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert Bitmap to Byte Array:-

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Pass byte array into intent:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Passing primitive types check the link below

[How do you pass a string from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859445/how-do-you-pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another/15859488#15859488)

Comment: I need to pass those images and others to a webservice. is it better to send it to as bytearray?

Comment: you are title says passing bitmaps(values in your title) between activities. does not mention about webservice. the answer is for passing bitmaps between activities. You should use http post request to send image to server