# Passing values through bundle and get its value on another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing value through Bundle as you can see in my code.

Now, I want its value in another activity `onCreate()`. I tried it to get its value but it is showing nullpointerexception.


Please help me solve the problem.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String url = "http://www.google.com";
bundle.putString("url", url);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
context.startService(myIntent);
```

**Get Value code :**

```
if (!getIntent().getExtras().getString("url").contains(null)) {
        // Do something
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859445/how-do-you-pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another/15859488#15859488. check this

Answer (score 31):

This should be the procedure.

Create a new Intent with bundle and start the activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityName.class);
i.putExtra("key", mystring);
startActivity(i);
```

Take the bundle like this in new Activity inside onCreate

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String value;
if (extras != null) {
  value = extras.getString("key");
}
```

Comment: change ActivityName.class

Not Class, its .class

Answer (score 25):

Hi i hope this code helps you.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "Android");
bundle.putString("iname", "iPhone");
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In MyActivity.class

```
public Bundle getBundle = null;
getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String name = getBundle.getString("name");
String id = getBundle.getString("iname");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("url") != null) {
        // retrieve the url
}
```

you have to check against null values

Answer (score 1):

//put value in intent like this

```
    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Booked.class);
    in.putExtra("filter", "Booked");
    startActivity(in);
```

// get value from bundle like this

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String filter = bundle.getString("filter");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String url = "http://www.google.com";

Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
myIntent.putExtras("url", url);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

and on another activity get it like

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extra != null) {
String value = extra.getString("url")
//use this value where ever you want

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `startService(...)` - > `startActivity(...)`

And Also replace

```
if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("url").contains(null)) {
        // retrieve the url
}
```

TO

```
if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("url") != null) {
        // retrieve the url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because you put your strings inside a bundle**

```
Bundle youtbundle = new Bundle();
String url = "http://www.google.com";
yourbundle.putString("url", url);
```

**And then put the bundle as an extra to the intent**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
myIntent.putExtras(yourbundle);
context.startService(myIntent);
```

**In the begining You have to strip the bundle from extras**

```
Bundle yourbundle = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("yourbundle") ;
```

**Then get Strings from yourbundle**

```
if (!yourbundle.getString("url").contains(null)) {
     // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String value = bundle.getString("request");

Answer (score 0):

1. Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourService.class.getName());
   serviceIntent.putExtra("url", "www.google.com");
   context.startService(serviceIntent);

   2. When the service is started its onStartCommand() method will be called so in this method you can fetch the value (url) from the intent object
   3. public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

   String userID = intent.getStringExtra("url");

   return START_STICKY;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this inside `NotificationService.class`:

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```