# how to pass JsonArray from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I'll Follow this SO links but can't helpful for me:

- [passing jsonarray from 1 activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686531/passing-jsonarray-from-1-activity-to-another?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Android passing JsonArray from one intent to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32929539/android-passing-jsonarray-from-one-intent-to-another?lq=1)
- [How to pass ArrayList<CustomeObject> from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another/21250450?noredirect=1#comment87834196_21250450)
- [How to pass a String array value from one activity to another Activity in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892916/how-to-pass-a-string-array-value-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-androi)

I am trying to send JSon Subcategory data from one activity to another activity

see below Json format:

[image]

In Above Json `data` is a get Main category's and `subcategory` get sub data

**now i'll get both data perfectly in one activity.**

**But** i am trying to Click on Main category's data and each main subcategory data pass on another activity

see below image to batter understanding:

[image]

**HOPE all users getting me**

Now for this what i tried

**`MainActivity.java`** class For getting JsonData:

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {

                    JSONArray jArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Pojo dataPojo = new Pojo();
                        dataPojo.setCatagory_id(json_data.getString("category_id"));
                        dataPojo.setCatagory_name(json_data.getString("category_name"));
                        dataPojo.setCatagory_thumbnailUrl(json_data.getString("category_image"));
                        dataList.add(dataPojo);

                        JSONArray jArray1 = json_data.getJSONArray("subcategory");

                    }

                    dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(dataList);
                    dataAdapter.setClickListener(jsonDataClickListener);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    //recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
```

**`MainActivity.java`** class for Passing SubCategory :

```
OnItemClickListener jsonDataClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Pojo item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubCategoryData.class);
        intent.putExtra("Key", (Serializable) dataList);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

**In Above code it's give me a `myList` size is `0`**

**`Pojo.java`** Model class:

public class Pojo extends Base implements Serializable{

```
    private String catagory_id;
    private String catagory_name;
    private String catagory_thumbnailUrl;
    private String childListSize;
    private ArrayList<Pojo2> subCatagoryArrayList;

    public ArrayList<Pojo2> getSubCatagoryArrayList() {
        return subCatagoryArrayList;
    }

    public void setSubCatagoryArrayList(ArrayList<Pojo2> subCatagoryArrayList) {
        this.subCatagoryArrayList = subCatagoryArrayList;
    }

    public String getCatagory_id() {
        return catagory_id;
    }

    public void setCatagory_id(String catagory_id) {
        this.catagory_id = catagory_id;
    }

    public String getCatagory_name() {
        return catagory_name;
    }

    public void setCatagory_name(String catagory_name) {
        this.catagory_name = catagory_name;
    }

    public String getCatagory_thumbnailUrl() {
        return catagory_thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setCatagory_thumbnailUrl(String catagory_thumbnailUrl) {
        this.catagory_thumbnailUrl = catagory_thumbnailUrl;
    }

}
```

**`Pojo2.java`** Model class for Subcategory :

```
public class Pojo2  {

    private String subcatagory_id;
    private String subcatagory_name;

    /*public Pojo2(String SubId, String SubName){
        super(SubId, SubName);
    }*/

    public String getSubcatagory_id() {
        return subcatagory_id;
    }

    public void setSubcatagory_id(String subcatagory_id) {
        this.subcatagory_id = subcatagory_id;
    }

    public String getSubcatagory_name() {
        return subcatagory_name;
    }

    public void setSubcatagory_name(String subcatagory_name) {
        this.subcatagory_name = subcatagory_name;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

When i used @Birju answer to send `ArrayList` it's work for me but where i receive data then it's give me a error.

**`java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String`**

and for Receiving a data i'll use Below Code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        if(b!=null)
        {

            String j =(String) b.getSerializable("Key");
            subId.setText(j);
        }
```

**BUT ABOVE ERROR COME EVERY TIME** How to i solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Onclicklistner`

```
ArrayList<Pojo> myList = new ArrayList<Pojo>(); // do not create new list....
                                                // every time creation its by default empty
intent.putExtra("SubCategory",myList);// use "dataList" instade of mylist
```

Instead of `mylist` you need to pass the **`dataList`** that you got from the json `response`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171529/discussion-between-birju-and-mohammad-ali).

Comment: so why your responce  @Override
        public void onItemClick(Base item) ....take Base item???

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `Serializable` interface to pass your data:

1. You must ensure that all inner field properties serializable => Your `Pojo2` must also implement `Serializable`
2. In your received activity, call:

   ```
   List<Pojo> story = (List<Pojo>) intent.getSerializableExtra("SubCategory");
   ```

   to get back the data.

Comment: 1st think is i want know how to i pass `subcategory` data. **?** after that i want received

Comment: Your `jsonDataClickListener` already pass the data. You just have to add desired data to that `ArrayList<Pojo> myList`

Comment: Sure its size is 0. You have to add like: `myList.add(item)`. Did you write that code?

Comment: i'll write for main category data like `dataList.add(dataPojo);` but for myList i'll write this line `ArrayList<Pojo> myList = new ArrayList<Pojo>();`

Comment: Then add item to `myList`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171368/discussion-between-mohammad-ali-and-mnh-quyt-nguyn).

Comment: I want to just simply pass the **`ArrayList`** Nothing to else please help me