# How to recive Image file with Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image

am sending an image with help of intent as follow

```
Uri profileImage = Uri.parse("android.resource://Tset/res/drawable-hdpi/arr.jpeg");
            details.setType("image/png");
            details.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, profileImage);
            startActivity(details);
```

how do i can get the image path in my receiving end activity ?

Comment: use intnet getExtra to get the uri with the key

Comment: @Raghunandan sorry ! what does key means to ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859445/how-do-you-pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another/15859488#15859488

Comment: yes i 've done it with reading up string values ! but i suspect whether it works with image ! i 'll try it and revert u ! Thank u !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i done it with help of id of the image as follow ! ! 
thanks for all of ur reply ! !

```
  profilePictureID=R.drawable.image name;//name of image in drawable folder dont use extensions like.jpg and all  
  IntentObject.putExtra("ImageID",profilePictureID);
  startActivity(IntenetObject);
```

In receiving activity

```
 int pictureId=getIntent().getIntExtra("ImageID",0);
 profilePicture.setImageResource(pictureId);
```

Comment: also this does not make sense since you can access the drawable image just be referring as R.drawable.imagename. and why did you unaccept my answer? for all my effort not even a upvote. very frustrating

Comment: @Raghunandan am not doing it for an image it's a part of my list view ! am having loads of image and based on the image gets clicks i need to send the Id of the image to next activity ! ! For a single image navigation i could directly refer it from my next activity with out intent message exchange of intent !

Comment: even then the edit part of my solution works you are passing an int id and not the uri.

Comment: also how can you know the name of the image on list item click. it should work dynamically in that case and you should include more info in your question. i don't think its a good approach

Comment: i 've defined a custom adapter that stores all the data belongs to list view i just instantiate the adapter in onCreate() so that i can access all the data in list ! !

Comment: that has nothing to with passing the drawable id. in any case post your code. you have to include more info. you have not provided anything. din't mention about listview or custom adapter

Comment: i wrapped those things that's why id didn't mention! my concern was just passing an intent to next activity with an image !

Comment: that's exactly what was answered in the answer posted

Answer (score 3):

Try This
Pass image url from current activity  using intent

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyImageViewActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("image", path);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

Here path is

```
String path="android.resource://Tset/res/drawable-hdpi/arr.jpeg"
```

in your receiving activity

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String path = bundle.getString("image");
```

Comment: bundle.putString("image", path); here how to pass the value for "path"?

Comment: @LiveITup can you explain what this is **android.resource://Tset/res/drawable-hdpi/arr.jpeg**. you can acess drawable in the other activity also. so if you explain will help us give better answer

Comment: this is the path of my image in drawable folder !

Comment: are the activities in the same package?? if so you can refer to the drawable in the next activity as R.drawable.imagename

Comment: @LiveITup like ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); ic_launcher as the iamge name

Comment: thanks for ur relaying helps ! ! i done it and post it as answer !

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```