# how to start another activity and send through additional data with android Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the following code that currently starts another activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FoodMenuActivity.this, FoodItemActivity.class);      
startActivity(intent);
```

Now I want to be able to send some data with to my FoodItemActivityClass.
Either some string variables or an object that i have made.  How would i go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859445/how-do-you-pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another/15859488#15859488. you can pass the string variables using intents. also check this http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Food Menu Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FodMenuActivity.this,FoodItemActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(TEXT,string_u_want_to_send);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your onCreate, add:

```
public final static String TEXT=your package name ;(like com.example.app)
```

In your oncreate in FoodItemActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getStringExtra(FoodMenuActivity.TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android).

> The easiest way to do this would be to pass the session id to the signout activity in the intent you're using to start the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent)
```

> The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) for Intents has more information (look at the section titled "Extras").