# Can i save data from firstActivity and secondActivity if the button save stay at secondActivity?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

if I have  some edittext in firstactivity and then I press button next to start the secondactivity .In secondActivity i have editText and button save then i press button save .I want to know  a edittext in firstActivity can add with editText in secondActivity ??

Comment: you need to pass the edittext data from first activity to second activity using intent. Get the data from edittext in first activity. use intent and pass the data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859445/how-do-you-pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another/15859488#15859488. retrieve the data in second activity and use the same

Comment: Can you rephrase a bit your question?

Comment: Thank you every much Ranghunandan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, just pass the data from the first Activity to the second when launching it.
Include the data in your Intent as explained here: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)