# How to use the value of edittext in Page1 to be passed on directly on edittext on Page 2?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Please give me an idea on how will I retrieve or pass the value of my edittext in my Page1.xml to the edittext in my Page2.xml.

For example, I have entered `1234` in the edittext in Page1.xml, when I pressed the button (which will redirect to my page 2 as well as it will pass the current value of my edittext in Page1.xml), I will see the `1234` in my edittext on my Page2.xml

How will I do that? Can you give me an idea or cite some example? Thanks!

Comment: By pages do you mean activities?

Comment: Yes. It is. I want to pass the content of my edittext in Page1.xml to the edittext of my Page2.xml when I clicked the button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass object from one activity to another in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use intents.

Here is some sample code

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {

private Bundle extras = new Bundle();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    final EditText note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myText);
    Button btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            extras.putString("text", note.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(extras);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

}
```

ActivityTwo

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_2);

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourText2);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

        name.setText(extras.getString("text"));

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `id` in `extras.putString("text", String.valueOf(id))` and where is `id` initialized?

Comment: Yea. What is on the id?

Comment: Sorry I edit some of my code and forgot to remove that bit I edited my answer now it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the string value from `edittext` use intent and pass the value to the other activity.

In Second Activity you need to retrieve the value and then set the same to edittext.

Example

[How do you pass a string from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859445/how-do-you-pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another/15859488#15859488)

Answer (score 0):

Using intents to pass from one activity to another would be your solution as I can guess.

`intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED",editText.getText());`

And in the receiving activity as

```
String newString;
Bundle extras;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      if(extras == null) {
      newString= null;
      } else {
            newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
      }
} else {
     newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
editText.setText(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use intents to pass values from one activity to other.

U can get value of the `EditText` in `FirstActivity` and save it in a `String` and with the help of intents on `onClick` of `Button` `putExtra` your `String`

eg.

In for FirstActivity

```
    butt.onClickListner
    {
    ...
   String editTextValue = editText.getText().toString();
    Intent i= new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class");
     i.putExtra("key",editTextValue );
    startActiivty(i);

    }
```

In your onCreate of SecondActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    String valueFromFirstActivity = extras.getString("Key");
   editText2.setText(valueFromFirstActivity );    //Set your editTextValue of first  
                                                  //activity in editText2 of                        
                                                  //second activity
}
```

Comment: Still showing blank on my edittext on my Second Page. Even when i entered 1234 in the edittext in my 1st activity, it shows none when I click the button to redirect.

Comment: I've edited my answer.Try it